# How to test sending transaction from zero address in truffle

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-test

I have some smart contract which has this function:

```
function someFunction() external returns (uint256) {
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "zero address");
        //some code....
        return 10;
    }
```

Then I run my test it stopped working

```
const {constants,expectRevert,BN} = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
//setting up ....
it("Must fail if caller has zero address", async () => {
        await expectRevert(myContract.someFunction({from:constants.ZERO_ADDRESS}),"zero address")
})
```

and return this error

> UnhandledRejections detected Promise {    Error: nonce
> **generation function failed or private key is invalid**
> at Transaction.sign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\transaction.js:292:1)
> at Transaction.exports.modules.564403.FakeTransaction.hash (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\dist\fake.js:63:1)
> ature.js:11:1)
> at Transaction.fakeHash [as hash] (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\transaction.js:18:1)
> nsaction.js:230:1)
> at RuntimeError.combine (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:42:1)
> at new RuntimeError (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:19:1)
> \fake.js:63:1)
> at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:94:1)
> at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\blockchain_double.js:568:1
> {
> uncaught: true   } } Error: nonce generation function failed or private key is invalid
> at Object.exports.sign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\secp256k1\lib\elliptic\index.js:207:1)
> at Object.sign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\secp256k1\lib\index.js:192:1)
> at Object.exports.ecsign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist\signature.js:11:1)
> at Transaction.exports.modules.994857.Transaction.sign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\dist\transaction.js:230:1)
> ure.js:11:1)
> at Transaction.sign (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\transaction.js:292:1)
> action.js:230:1)
> at Transaction.exports.modules.564403.FakeTransaction.hash (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\dist\fake.js:63:1)
> ake.js:63:1)
> at Transaction.fakeHash [as hash] (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\transaction.js:18:1)
> at RuntimeError.combine (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:42:1)
> at new RuntimeError (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:19:1)
> at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:94:1)
> at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\blockchain_double.js:568:1
> {   uncaught: true }

I used solidity-coverage for testing.

Is it possible to check sending transaction from zero address?

How I can fix this?

Comment: You need to have the private key of the address to make a transaction, zero address is the public address.

Comment: @trizin Yes, I understand this, but I don't know how to add private key for zero address in ganache-cli or truffle( Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No idea. I suggest that you skip this test. Your require statement looks good and will most likely work.

Comment: @trizin I agree with you ) After continuous research I can say that easy way for testing sending from zero address doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can have zero address. To be more precise given an address, it is impossible to find the private key correspond to that address. If anybody can do it then the whole world will collapse not just blockchain but the whole modern society as we know it.

So you don't need to check the zero address because nobody can have it. Zero address is just a place people dump their money to it. It is like a whole world garbage dump but the garbage is money